# Tornado as Game engine and backend

Tags: python, real-time, tornado, sockjs

I am going to build a simple monopoly game in realtime. 
**Game constraints:**

- 3-8 people in one game
- Realtime switching between players
- Scores and other stat
- Start pos and Finish pos
- Receiving answer from specific player and check it in realtime

So, I've decided to use SockJS as realtime(comet) server. Could you advice me some py game framework pluggable with SockJS or it is better to right game engine from scratch ? 
Examples are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to write own one, because most of solutions are simple, and it's better to build something specific based on https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado/
The combination of Tornado + SockJS + Redis could be your way

Comment: Yeaah, I've started already. Thank you. I am going to use memcached.